# Console.log() devuelve un valor y la funcion devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, funciones, lógica

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion que devuelva el siguiente primo mas proximo. Pareceria que en principio esta ok la funcion que hice pero no, porque devuelve *undefined*. Aqui el codigo:

```js
function siguientePrimo(numero) {
  let number = numero + 1;
  let count = 1;
  let dividers = 0;
  while (count <= number) {
    if (number % count == 0) {
      dividers++;
    }
    count++;
  }
  if (dividers == 2) {
    console.log(number);
    return number;
  } else {
    siguientePrimo(number);
  }
}


console.log(siguientePrimo(-5));
console.log(siguientePrimo(11));
```

Lo que me pregunto es porque si el console.log(number) me devuelve el valor correcto/esperado, el return no lo hace.

Comment: En la parte del _else_ no estás devolviendo un valor, coloca `return` antes de llamar nuevamente a la función y listo.

Comment: Gracias! no sabia ese detalle. Saludos

Comment: Para que funcione, siempre debe devolver un valor, incluso si es generado por una llamada recursiva.

Answer (score 2):

Como te lo comentaron, el problema es que la definición de tu problema es recursiva, si no mandas a llamar a la función dentro de sí misma ese valor se perderá, y solo existirá en el ámbito local para todos los casos en que los divisores no sean exactamente dos y deba buscar el siguiente primo.

```js
function siguientePrimo(numero) {
  let number = numero + 1;
  let count = 1;
  let dividers = 0;
  while (count <= number) {
    if (number % count == 0) {
      dividers++;
    }
    count++;
  }
  if (dividers == 2) {
    console.log(number);
    return number;
  } else {
    return siguientePrimo(number);
  }
}


console.log(siguientePrimo(-5));
console.log(siguientePrimo(11));
```